# How to fix the difference I'm getting in the google map distance and my google map API distance calculation?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The problem I'm facing is that google maps show the distance from 1st location to 2nd location to be around 4 and my calculation is showing 4.8km?

I have tired other solutions to such as Haversine formula but the problem is still there. Is there any problem with my code ?

```
<script>
    var p1 = new google.maps.LatLng(24.8739756, 67.0650871);
    var p2 = new google.maps.LatLng(24.9041034, 67.1001688);

    alert(calcDistance(p1, p2));

    //calculates distance between two points in km's
    function calcDistance(p1, p2) {
        return (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(p1, 
        p2) / 1000).toFixed(2);
    }
</script>
```

I expect the output to be 4 but it gives 4.8 km.

Comment: No the correct distance is ~4.8km.

Comment: Why do you believe the result should be 4km?

Comment: @geocodezip I have check the distance on google map website so I'm bit confused as it also considers traffic and different routes?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a Google Map that shows a 4 km distance?  It is likely not the same two locations, as it is probably driving distance, while the code you posted is straight line distance.

Comment: @geocodezip Oh I got it by the way here is the link:

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/47+NKCHS+Union+Road,+Maniya+CHS+(MCHS)+PECHS,+Karachi,+Karachi+City,+Sindh,+Pakistan/Aga+Khan+University+Hospital,+Karachi/@24.8832022,67.0547051,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x3eb33eecdee0b627:0xb5de663b929eb79b!2m2!1d67.061669!2d24.8783841!1m5!1m1!1s0x3eb33edc6300d3e9:0xc1a0bebaaddca5aa!2m2!1d67.075502!2d24.8927887

Answer (score 0):

The [map you posted](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/47+NKCHS+Union+Road,+Maniya+CHS+(MCHS)+PECHS,+Karachi,+Karachi+City,+Sindh,+Pakistan/Aga+Khan+University+Hospital,+Karachi/@24.8832022,67.0547051,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x3eb33eecdee0b627:0xb5de663b929eb79b!2m2!1d67.061669!2d24.8783841!1m5!1m1!1s0x3eb33edc6300d3e9:0xc1a0bebaaddca5aa!2m2!1d67.075502!2d24.8927887) has start  (24.8783841, 67.0616689), end 24.89203, 67.074753); not the coordinates in the posted code and displays driving distance, not straight line (great circle distance), which is what the posted code calculates.  If I use the same coordinates as the Google Map, it gives me a result of 2.01km, not 4km.

Proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/wobyj51c/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var fenway = {
    lat: 42.345573,
    lng: -71.098326
  };
  var p1 = new google.maps.LatLng(24.8739756, 67.0650871);
  var p2 = new google.maps.LatLng(24.9041034, 67.1001688);
  createMap(1, p1, p2);
  var p3 = new google.maps.LatLng(24.8783841, 67.0616689);
  var p4 = new google.maps.LatLng(24.89203, 67.074753);
  createMap(2, p3, p4);
}

function createMap(id, p1, p2) {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map' + id));
  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: p1,
    map: map
  });
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: p2,
    map: map
  });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  bounds.extend(p1);
  bounds.extend(p2);
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  document.getElementById('distance' + id).innerHTML = calcDistance(p1, p2);
}
//calculates distance between two points in km's
function calcDistance(p1, p2) {
  return (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(p1,
    p2) / 1000).toFixed(2)+" km";
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#mapcontainer1 {
  float: left;
  height: 90%;
  width: 50%;
}

#mapcontainer2 {
  float: right;
  height: 90%;
  width: 50%;
}

.map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="mapcontainer1">
  <div id="distance1"></div>
  <div id="map1" class="map"></div>
</div>
<div id="mapcontainer2">
  <div id="distance2"></div>
  <div id="map2" class="map"></div>
</div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize&libraries=geometry">
</script>
```